# Geth mining stuck: Commit new mining work on Ubuntu instance

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ubuntu, aws, mastering-ethereum

I have an Ubuntu instance running on aws ec2. I'm currently using Ubuntu server ec2 instance with the configuration as: **1 vCPU, 2.5 GHz, Intel Xeon Family, 1 GiB memory**.
I'm running my Geth on this using command

```
geth --datadir ./Doc-Nodes --networkid 4780 --port 30306 --rpc --rpcapi "db,personal,eth,net,web3,debug,admin" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpcport 8545 --allow-insecure-unlock console
```

The issue arises in the case of mining. Whenever I'm trying to mine the blocks on this instance using `miner.start()` ,  it gets stuck at for a long time.

> Commit new mining work

While the same is working when I'm running the Geth locally on my machine.

What's the issue behind this? Do I need to increase the Ubuntu configurations?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a PoW blockchain? The first time it has to generate the DAG for the proof of work it should take several minutes. If you can I'd try a PoA with a single validator. You can also add `--verbosity 5` to have more logging to try to understand what is wrong.

Comment: @Ismael Yes, it's a PoW. DAG has been already generated. I tried `--verbosity 5` and it says that `Ethereum handshake failed. Genesis block mismatch`. Then I checked all these things mentioned 
 [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/47907/53398). Everything's correct. Once it starts working, I'll shift to PoA.

Comment: The handshake failed seems unrelated more like some other node is trying to connect. Another possibility with PoW mining is that your difficulty is too high.

Comment: @Ismael I tried it by reducing the difficulty, but is of no use.